# Remove konsole split tab's title bar

Tags: kde, split, konsole

I would like to remove the titlebar, the one just above my prompt, which has the fullscreen and close button.
I only find options to edit the tab bar (Ctrl+Shift+t), just under the menu list, but nothing for the annoying large bar on every splitted window. I want to have a look similar to terminator when splitted, with no extra bars.
I don't know if it's even possible

I am using:

- Konsole 19.12.0
- KDE plasma 5.17.4
- Fedora 30

[image]

Comment: Useful question. I've been looking for an answer. Have you considered filing a bug to kde ?
If the fearture doesn't exist, it could definitely be useful.
I believe there is a tab bar stylesheet and assiciate style options, mayber there could be similar setiings, or ideally as profile options.

Answer (score 2):

Do this and you will have what you see in the Youtube video

1. Settings > Configure Konsole Ctrl+Shift+,
2. Tab Bar / Splitters > Splits
3. "Show Header": Never

[image]

Comment: There is no "Tab Bar / Splitters" in my settings. Only "Tab Bar". Nothing in there for splits.

Comment: The dialog is accessed through "Configure Konsole `(Ctrl+Shift+,)`". And my Konsole is Version 20.12.2.

Comment: It worked for me on konsole version 21.04.2

Answer (score -1):

As said here : https://www.reddit.com/r/unixporn/comments/4gez8w/hide_title_bars_in_kde_plasma_5/

```
1. Navigate: System Settings -> Application Style -> Window Decorations
2. Click one of the themes context menu icon
3. Navigate: Window Specific Overrides -> Add
4. Click "Hide window title bar"
5. Use .* for the regular expression to match all windows
```

But you should adjust the regex to only match konsole.

see xprop to get informations on the window name and class

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't want to hide the window titlebar with the colored buttons but the bar with the two white buttons on the right, which appears above every prompt, to have something like in this video: https://youtu.be/85ROY3XWwyU?t=68

Comment: Completely unrelated to the question asked, and completely unnecessasry. If you did want to hide the titlebar, Konsole has its own "Remove window titlebar and frame" checkbox in its settings.